# How to distinguish histograms having two distinctive peaks?

Tags: computational-statistics, histogram

I have two categories of histograms, one of them has two very distinctive peaks (not necessarily at the same bins/locations every time). What might be a good algorithm/method to find out such histograms? One example-

With peaks:
[image: With peaks]
Without peaks:
[image: Without peaks]